# Program (CCleaner) shows wrong installation date?

Tags: installation, ccleaner

I installed CCleaner a few days ago (forgot the exact date, uninstalled it) and when I checked control panel for the list of programs it says I installed it on April 23, 2013!

What's going on? My computer's date and time is correct, and I never changed it.

It was my first time installing this program. My OS is Windows 7 Starter.

Comment: What version of CCleaner?

Comment: @Ofiris The latest version, Version 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Well, its a bug which was supposed to be fixed in version 3.20.1750

From [enter link description here](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/version-history)

> v3.20.1750 (25 Jun 2012)
>   - Improved accuracy for uninstall items installation date and size.

Try newer version.

Moreover, programs sometimes writes installation date to:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\`

Look for you program there, find `install date`, you can see you can change it and you will see difference in the control panel.

Comment: Well it is the control panel that is showing the wrong installation date of CCleaner itself (I'm not looking at CCleaner's program list) so I think this might be a Windows problem. What do you think?

Comment: My bet is that during installation, the program modifies its registry key which determines its installation date.

Comment: I checked it out and it it a registry issue, I will expand my answer.
I changed Itunes `InstallDate` value to some other date and the value in the control panel has changed.
Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429738/detecting-installed-programs-via-registry

Comment: Note that at least for me on Windows 7, as of CCleaner 4.05.4250 64bit, this problem has not been fixed. I thought I was going crazy, but it was in the registry just as Ofiris said, and responds to changes in the Registry. Weird.